# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I believe this may be a syntax error, but I cannot find it.

This is the full error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax
>   near ','.    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__164_0(Task`1
>   result)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
>   currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject
>   parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject
>   parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject
>   parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext
>   _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   FincredixAppBigBrotherWebApi.Application.Sucursales.Queries.GetAllSucursales.GetAllSucursalesHandler.Handle(GetAllSucursalesQuery
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   C:\Users\alozano\source\repos\FincredixAppBigBrotherWebApi\FincredixAppBigBrotherWebApi.Application\Sucursales\Queries\GetAllSucursales\GetAllSucursalesHandler.cs:line
>   28    at
>   MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)    at
>   MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)    at
>   MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)    at
>   MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)    at
>   MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)    at
>   MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)    at
>   MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)    at
>   FincredixAppBigBrotherWebApi.WebApi.Controllers.SucursalController.GetAll(Int32
>   claSucursal, Int32 claSucursalPadre, Int32 bajaLogica, String
>   descripcion) in
>   C:\Users\alozano\source\repos\FincredixAppBigBrotherWebApi\FincredixAppBigBrotherWebApi.WebApi\Controllers\SucursalController.cs:line
>   19    at lambda_method(Closure , Object )    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
>   invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
>   isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
>   isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
>   isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
>   endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context) ClientConnectionId:25b62d0a-cacd-4e27-aa37-90c4cd002382 Error
>   Number:102,State:1,Class:15
>
> HEADERS
>   ======= Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: keep-alive Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Host: localhost:5001 User-Agent:
>   PostmanRuntime/7.22.0 Postman-Token:
>   bdd4ae12-be9d-4d55-9753-36f00ca7029c

This is the line of code I suspect

> at
>   FincredixAppBigBrotherWebApi.Application.Sucursales.Queries.GetAllSucursales.GetAllSucursalesHandler.Handle(GetAllSucursalesQuery
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   C:\Users\alozano\source\repos\FincredixAppBigBrotherWebApi\FincredixAppBigBrotherWebApi.Application\Sucursales\Queries\GetAllSucursales\GetAllSucursalesHandler.cs:line
>   28

And this is the line 28:

```
public async Task<List<SucursalViewModel>> Handle(GetAllSucursalesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = this._mapper.Map<List<SucursalViewModel>>(await this._fincredixAppDbContext.SpAppFcxSucursalSel.FromSqlRaw(
                    $@"{SpConstants.SpAppFcxSucursalSel}
                    @pnClaSucursal = { request.ClaSucursal },
                    @psDescripcion = { request.Descripcion },
                    @pnClaSucursalPadre = { request.ClaSucursalPadre },
                    @pnIncBajaLogica = { request.BajaLogica }")
                    .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(cancellationToken));
    return response;
}
```

I have already seen many questions very similar to this one but the Incorrect syntaxes are '?' or ')' or 'from' or '/' etc. Mine is ','

Comment: Don't build SQL with string concatenation. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: You may get this error if any of your variables contains SQL special characters. Follow Daniel's advice.

Comment: I know how to make a parameterized query, but not in the current situation where I have to return a list of a certain ViewModel, plus its gotta be asynchronous.

Comment: What is the resulting SQL query when this runs?  At the risk of sounding sarcastic, I think we should look near a "," for a syntax error

Comment: The stored procedure runs fine when exec inside SSMS, so I know the problem is not the sp. Yeah I hear you, its not sarcastic, there must be some comma either missing or being extra. I just dont know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
 $@"{SpConstants.SpAppFcxSucursalSel}
                    @pnClaSucursal = '{request.ClaSucursal}',
                    @psDescripcion = '{request.Descripcion}',
                    @pnClaSucursalPadre = '{request.ClaSucursalPadre}',
                    @pnIncBajaLogica = '{request.BajaLogica}'")
```

Comment: I'll try that first thing in the morning, but I have my doubts, because when I debug and set a breakpoint at that line, when I hover over the 4 parameters, they have the expected values from the request.

Comment: That did it! Putting the request parameters inside single quotes made it work like a charm, thank you very much.

Comment: This worked for me too (as of Dec 2022)!! Thank you for the answer.